# Preload image doesn't always appear

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have created a simple ajax request:

```
             var params = "postdata=" + mydata;
             if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             } else {
                 xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                     document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                 }
             }
             xmlhttp.open("POST", "data.php", true);
             xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
             xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
             xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
             xmlhttp.send(params);
```

And this is the HTML code:

```
    <div id="data">
    <img src="/images/preload.gif" />
    <b style="color:#9ca6dc;font-size:12px;">Wait</b>
    </div>
```

The problem is that the preload.gif and "Wait" text appears only sometimes and not always.

Why ? How can I resolve that ?

Comment: Maybe it's fast enough you can't see it

Comment: Try one or both from to find problem: 1. Replace your `<img src="/images/preload.gif" />` _src_ attribute value with _data:_ url instead of _http:_ (for example, `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,........" />` 2. If possible, on server side script (data.php) add code to temporary suspend thread (thread sleep) for 30 seconds (+-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only explanation is that AJAX request works too quickly to see the content (as Alessandro Pezzato said). If you don't see it the readyState of XMLHTTP request had to change.

Or you have some other Javascript which runs asynchronously and does changes on the same content.

Comment: There isn't others javascript that changes the same content. However if I push F5 then the preload appears. So I don't know :(